# How to save results of a function into text file in C

Tags: c

This function print the length of words with '*' called histogram.How can I save results into text file? I tried but the program does not save the results.(no errors)

```
void histogram(FILE *myinput)
   {
   FILE *ptr;
   printf("\nsaving results...\n");
   ptr=fopen("results1.txt","wt");

   int j, n = 1, i = 0;
   size_t ln;
   char arr[100][10];

   while(n > 0)
      {
      n = fscanf(myinput, "%s",arr[i]);
      i++;
      }

   n = i;
   for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
      {
      ln=strlen(arr[i]);
      fprintf(ptr,"%s \t",arr[i]);
      for(j=0;j<ln;j++) 
         fprintf(ptr, "*");

      fprintf(ptr, "\n");
      }

   fclose(myinput);
   fclose(ptr);
   }
```

Comment: How did you try to do it? How did it "stop working"?

Comment: I edited don't down vote plz!

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to take care of this issue:

1. Open a file in the program and write to it.
2. If running with command line, change the output location for standard out

   $> ./histogram > outfile.txt

Using the '>' will change where standard out will write to. The issue with '>' is that it will truncate a file and then write to the file. This means that if there was any data in that file before, it is gone. Only the new data written by the program will be there.

If you need to keep the data in the file, you can change the standard out to append the file with '>>' as in the following example:

```
$> ./histogram >> outfile.txt
```

Also, there does not have to be a space between '>' and the file name. I just do that for preference. It could look like this:

```
$> ./histogram >outfile.txt
```

If your writing to a file will be a one time thing, changing standard out is probably be best way to go. If you are going to do it every time, then add it to the code.

You will need to open another FILE. You can do this in the function or pass it in like you did the file being read from.

Use 'fprintf' to write to the file:

```
int fprintf(FILE *restrict stream, const char *restrict format, ...);
```

Your program may have these lines added to write to a file:

```
FILE *myoutput = fopen("output.txt", "w"); // or "a" if you want to append
fprintf(myoutput, "%s \t",arr[i]);
```

**Answer Complete**

There may be some other issues as well that I will discuss now.

Your histogram function does not have a return identifier. C will set it to 'int' automatically and then say that you do not have a return value for the function. From what you have provided, I would add the 'void' before the function name.

```
void histogram {
```

The size of arr's second set of arrays may be to small. One can assume that the file you are reading from does not exceed 10 characters per token, to include the null terminator [\0] at the end of the string. This would mean that there could be at most 9 characters in a string. Else you are going to overflow the location and potentially mess your data up.

**Edit**

The above was written before a change to the provided code that now includes a second file and fprintf statements.

I will point to the line that opens the out file:

```
ptr=fopen("results1.txt","wt");
```

I am wondering if you mean to put "w+" where the second character is a plus symbol. According to the man page there are six possibilities:

> The argument mode points to a string beginning with one of the
>          following sequences (possibly followed by additional characters, as
>          described below):

```
   r      Open text file for reading.  The stream is positioned at the
          beginning of the file.

   r+     Open for reading and writing.  The stream is positioned at the
          beginning of the file.

   w      Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing.
          The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

   w+     Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does
          not exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is
          positioned at the beginning of the file.

   a      Open for appending (writing at end of file).  The file is
          created if it does not exist.  The stream is positioned at the
          end of the file.

   a+     Open for reading and appending (writing at end of file).  The
          file is created if it does not exist.  The initial file
          position for reading is at the beginning of the file, but
          output is always appended to the end of the file.
```

As such, it appears you are attempting to open the file for reading and writing.

Comment: Thank you anyway! But what is wrong with the new code can you post the corrected code?

Comment: Still can't find out why does not save the results!

Comment: The text file is blank!

Comment: This is vague. We don't know how you open your input, as it was on your function parameters. Are you passing by argv on main? If you are, are you setting on run the correct file?  Try to printf the 
read string from input (and check), to make sure you're reading correctly.

Also, try to put w instead of wt on fopen:
 ptr=fopen("results1.txt","w");

Comment: @user3599630, make sure you close the file. Often times, if a program terminates with out closing a file, the buffer that the program is writing to may not be flushed properly. Since you did a fopen, the program writes to a buffer which then gets written to the file when convenient for the OS.